# How to reuse an already executing asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Scenario :
In `activity1` user clicks a fileName. `Activity 2` is invoked and it downloads the file showing progress.

An asynctask exists ,in  `Activity 2`,whose work is to download and open file.

AsyncTask does the following things in its various methods:

- `onPreExecute` :- Opens a progress bar.
- `doInbackground` :- Initiates download and send progress update
- `onPostExecute` :-handles various return values sent by `doInBackground`.

While it's downloading it also updates the progress.

Now as the progressbar `oncancelable` is `true` .So when the user presses back it goes back to last activity.

But when the user presses the same file again in `Activity1` either he should see the progress bar again if the download is still going and post that `onPostExecute` should be executed.

How may I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use services

Comment: You cannot use asynctask here

Answer (score 1):

Create a static object of the Asysnc task and check its status on resuming the `Activity`

```
static YourAsyncTask backgroundTask;
```

In `onCreate()`/`onResume()`

```
if(backgroundTask == null)
{
    backgroundTask = new YourAsyncTask();
    backgroundTask.execute();
}
else
{
    if(backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
        // AsyncTask has not started yet
    }

    if(backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING){
        // AsyncTask is currently doing work in doInBackground()
    }

    if(backgroundTask.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
        // AsyncTask is done and onPostExecute was called
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)