# Android Studio - download JSON data from 2 urls in one Async Task

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I can download data using the downloadJSON class for 1 URL using the below code no problem, but I want to get another set of data so it can be displayed with the other. I've tried several different method but to no avail.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_json);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.JSONTextView);
    textView.setText("Downloading JSON!");
    new downloadJSON().execute("www.exampleURL.com/data1");
   //new downloadJSON().execute(url2??);
}

private class downloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String result = "";
        String formattedResult = "";

        try {
            InputStream stream = (InputStream)new URL(args[0]).getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                result += line;
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            formattedResult = "Downloadable Puzzles\r\n--------------\r\n";



            JSONArray puzzles = json.getJSONArray("PuzzleIndex");


            for (int i = 0;i < puzzles.length(); ++i) {
                formattedResult += puzzles.get(i) + "\r\n";

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedResult;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String pResult) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.JSONTextView);
        textView.setText(pResult);
    }
}
```

Edit: my question is not a duplicate of the link posted below as my question has much more weight to it with the fact that JSON and URL's are involved. The link is in no way specific to my problem and doesn't help the question.

Comment: what methods have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: @SoroushA nothing worth reporting, im new to android so looking for advice

Comment: new downloadJSON().execute(url2) didn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reuse an already executing asynctask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680535/how-to-reuse-an-already-executing-asynctask)

Comment: @SoroushA nope, hence the question. url2 is just there to show what I am looking to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The Async task doesn't return the control to the calling method.* It only runs the onPostExecute() in the main thread after completing the doInBackground() on a background thread.

One approach to transfer control back into calling method is to use interface.

```
public class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private AsyncCallback mCallback;

    public DownloadJSON(AsyncCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // process background task
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onComplete(result);
    }

    public interface AsyncCallback {
        void onComplete(String result);
    }
}
```

And then start asynctask using

```
new DownloadJSON(new DownloadJSON.AsyncCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
}).execute("www.exampleURL.com/data1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply. would I do the same for the second link?

Comment: yes. pass the second url. You can use it as many times you want

Comment: I will but i did receive a static error when implementing the interface part, saying that the class has to be static to use the interface

Comment: You should make a separate file for DownloadJSON class

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to abandon this old way of picking a thread from thread pool and execute this heavy operation at background thread

check out this awesome lib. [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)